# How to validate data sent through post?

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have ajax code that sends `postid` and `comment` to another page.

ajax.php

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addcomment.php",
            data: {comment : comment,postid : postid},
```

I receive data on other page as:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $postid=$_POST['postid'];
    $comment=$_POST['comment'];
```

Here what improvements I can make to validate the second code. I mean code should proceed only if `postid` and `comment` has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just check that they are defined...

```
if (isset($_POST['postid']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {
     //continue
} else {
    // do not continue
}
```

Or you can do it before you make the AJAX call.  Where you grab the value for the postid and comment elements, just check that they have a value.  If not return from function.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's a few things you can do, first of all you want to ensure that both of the variables exist, which you can do with an `isset()`

For code like this I tend to favour early returns over nested ifs, so you could do something like:

```
if (!isset($_POST['postid']) || !isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    $error = 'Values for postid and comment were not set.';
    return $error;
}
```

Once you have checked that both variables are set, you could begin to validate whether the variables are the right type and size.

You could potentially replace `isset()` with `empty()` so:

```
if (empty($_POST['postid'] || empty($_POST['comment']) {
    $error = 'Values are not set.';
    return $error;
}
```

For example I presume `postid` is a numeric so...

```
if (!is_numeric($_POST['postid'])) {
    $error = 'Value for postid must be numeric.';
    return $error;
}
```

You could also do a check that it is above 0: `if (!$_POST['postid'] > 0) {}`

Then for comment you could check that the length is greater than 0.

```
if (!strlen($_POST['comment']) > 0) {
    $error = 'Comment was left blank, ensure it is filled in.';
    return $error;
}
```

So that's just a few examples to get you started, hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a general purpose Validator class, which will be configured differently according to the form you're going to validate (easily done with a configuration array or file).
This way you'll have to do the work only once and you'll be able to re-use it across your project, also making your code cleaner and easy to maintain.